# Nesting UISplitViewController within UINavigationController

Tags: ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I would like to have a root level controller that appears to be a splitview but I would also like to allow the detail view to essentially take over the entire screen (in both landscape and portrait orientation) - and not as a modal view.

By way of context, my iPad app shows the user a list of experiments (collections of data sampled from sensors) in the master view. Selecting an experiment causes details of experiment (e.g., title, sample rate, etc.) to be displayed in detail view. But I would also like to be able to tap on a button in the detail view and transition to a full-screen graph of, for example, data vs. time.

So, I am wondering if anyone has done this. I already have tried it the other way (uinavigationcontroller within detail view of splitviewcontroller) but that doesn't seem to allow for the full-screen aspect.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a modal view overlay with a full page style would give you what you want.

```
YourVc * vc = [[[YourVc alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourVc" bundle:nil] autorelease];
[self.splitViewController presentModalViewController:vc animated: true];
```

The default style for the overlaid modal view controller will take up the entire screen (it won't be a popup.)

Comment: MikeN, thanks. I will try this. There may be issues in that the view controller that I want to show (full-screen) is, itself, a navigation controller.